# Angular Unit testing a method that does not have any return statement

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test

My method :

```js
flyout() {
    document.getElementById("transition1").style.cssText="transform:translateX(-120%)";
    document.getElementById("transition2").style.cssText="transform:translateY(-120%)";
}
```

**spec.ts :**

```js
it('Tesing Void function', function() {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    component.flyOut();
    // How should I write expect statement
});
```

Can anyone help me how to write expect statment....

Thanks.!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can query your element in your expect and check whether the style has been applied or not.

```
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#transition1')).style.transform).toEqual('translateX(-120%)');
```

Comment: But this style only changes on clicking a button in the front end...so i cannot expect same css unless it is clicked.

Comment: But you are calling the method in your test `component.flyOut()`, so the style should change.